# Why would a small script continue using 70%+ of CPU after executing?

Tags: python, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I am very new to Python, but this does not make sense to me, here's an example script:

```
import pygame as py
import  time

py.init()
song = py.mixer.Sound("pineSiskin.wav") # c1Mb/20sec long
song.play(0 , 9000)
time.sleep(8)
song.fadeout(800)
py.quit()
print("quit")
```

Running this on  a Raspberry Pi*, the CPU goes up to 75% and ***stays there*** until I restart the Python shell. This soon leads to overheating on the RPi.
Other questions ([*like this one & other mentioned in link*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729689/python-gui-programming-and-cpu-usage-how-does-one-create-an-idle-or-throttle?noredirect=1&lq=1)), are dissimilar as they refer to scripts which have not completed.
This link does hint that what I'm seeing is not "normal" behaviour.

Any help to track this problem/diagnostic advice would be useful.

Apologies if I've made a mistake about which forum; tell me and I'll move it!

*Hardware/Software:

- Raspberry Pi 3 Model B running
- Raspbian Jessie Pixel
- Python 3.4.2
  accessed via IDLE3 Python 3.4.2 as bundled with scipi & matplotlib
  added

Comment: Just to reiterate you're running this from the Python REPL ("shell") and not strictly from the terminal (`python MyScript.py`)?

Comment: @KDecker, not from the Terminal, from IDLE ("Python’s Integrated Development and Learning Environment.") -  I'm guessing that's a shell!

Comment: What indication is there that the CPU is being used by the script as opposed to the IDE? If the script is run by itself, ie in a separate file executed in a terminal window, do you see same behaviour? As an aside, no, an IDE is not a shell :)

Comment: @KDecker, further to remark1:As noob, I hadn't tried running direct from Terminal. just done this with addition of full path to sound file: CPU dropped back to 0% *immediately* after script ended. So where to look for problems with IDLE (q to self)? Incidentally, the bundled Python games cause same problem which is why I didn't point the finger at the IDE.

Comment: @danny: *"What indication is there that the CPU is being used by the script"* -none; how would I glean this info? As a linux noob too, would **htop**  help delve into this?

Comment: @cate If you ran it from the terminal and not IDLE and it dropped the CPU usage immediately, then the CPU usage is obviously from IDLE. // I will have to leave the answer as to why to others, I am not well versed in its usage.

Comment: @KDecker yep, this problem has now become an IDLE3 question. remind me where I mark the q as being answered  by you.

Comment: @cate, someone has to post an answer first for it to be accepted by you the asker. I won't post one because it doesn't do much for the site other others who might view the question (in my opinion that is). I'd just delete the question and re-ask it in terms of IDLE usage.

Answer (score 0):

this problem turned out to be an OS problem. recreating the Raspbian OS from a new disk image solved it. Now scripts are behaving as I'd expect.